# How to replace a for loop with map_dl in R

Tags: r, dictionary, for-loop, tidyverse, purrr

i wanted to modify the values of a column whithin a table (dataframe that has 2 column and multiple rows) applying a condition for every row of the second column which, if verified, copyes the values of that cell and paste it into the same row of the first column.

So i wrote a code that does exactly that using a for loop that runs for every row (i) of the table.

The code works well but i would like to learn how to do the same thing with tidyverse, in particular using the map_dl function. I searched everywhere but i didn't manage to understad properly how to use the map_df function.

Here's the code with the for loop:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble (Color  = "A",
                  Names = c("Jane Yellow", "Max", "Jeff", "Andy", "Lux Yellow", "Elizabeth", "Susan", "David Yellow", "Thomas", "Lisa"))

col_color <- function(df) { 
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(grepl("Yellow", df[i,2], fixed=TRUE) == TRUE)
    {df[i,1]<- str_extract(df[i,2], "^(?!.*\bYellow\b).*$")}}
  
  for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df[i,1] == "A") 
    {df[i,1] <- df[i-1,1]}}
  return(df)
}
df <- col_color(df)
```

I tried to do it with map_dl with the code below but it doesn't work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble (Color  = "A",
                  Names = c("Jane Yellow", "Max", "Jeff", "Andy", "Lux Yellow", "Elizabeth", "Susan", "David Yellow", "Thomas", "Lisa"))

modify_first_column <- function(i) {
  
  if(grepl("Yellow", df[i,2], fixed=TRUE) == TRUE)
  {df[i,1]<- str_extract(df[i,2], "^(?!.*\bYellow\b).*$")}
  
  if(df[i,1] == "A") 
  {df[i,1] <- df[i-1,1]}
  return(df)
}

modify_first_column <- as.tibble(modify_first_column)
df <- map_df(i = 1:nrow(df), modify_first_column)
```

Can someone help me figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks for warning me so nicely, i edited the question to include the line of code that creates the tibble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem, though without loop or map. But it is within the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Your data:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   color names       
   <chr> <chr>       
 1 A     Jane Yellow 
 2 A     Max         
 3 A     Jeff        
 4 A     Andy        
 5 A     Lux Yellow  
 6 A     Elizabeth   
 7 A     Susan       
 8 A     David Yellow
 9 A     Thomas      
10 A     Lisa
```

First condition:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(str_detect(names, "Yellow") ~ names,
                           TRUE ~ color))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   color        names       
   <chr>        <chr>       
 1 Jane Yellow  Jane Yellow 
 2 A            Max         
 3 A            Jeff        
 4 A            Andy        
 5 Lux Yellow   Lux Yellow  
 6 A            Elizabeth   
 7 A            Susan       
 8 David Yellow David Yellow
 9 A            Thomas      
10 A            Lisa
```

Second condition:

```
df %>%
  mutate(color = replace(color, color == "A", NA)) %>%
  fill(color)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   color        names       
   <chr>        <chr>       
 1 Jane Yellow  Jane Yellow 
 2 Jane Yellow  Max         
 3 Jane Yellow  Jeff        
 4 Jane Yellow  Andy        
 5 Lux Yellow   Lux Yellow  
 6 Lux Yellow   Elizabeth   
 7 Lux Yellow   Susan       
 8 David Yellow David Yellow
 9 David Yellow Thomas      
10 David Yellow Lisa
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just for curiosity tho, is there a way to actually code the same actions with map? I'm very used to for loops to solve my problems and i'm trying to learn my way into map functions, but even after studying the book and looking for many examples here i didn't manage to understand how to apply it into this case, expecially with the function "if" inside the function.

Comment: @Josho I understand. But I really struggle to come up with a method with `map()` unfortunately.

Comment: @Josho `map` is meant to process lists. If instead of one df you had a list of df's, then `map` would be a solution, like this it's not needed.